# remove starting and ending comma from variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

i have the below variable in javascript. i want to remove the starting and ending "comma" sign using jquery/javascript

```
var test=",1,2,3,4," <--- 

Expected output: var test="1,2,3,4"
```

please advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove unwanted commas in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665829/remove-unwanted-commas-in-javascript)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Regex should help

```
var edited = test.replace(/^,|,$/g,'');
```

`^,` matches the comma at the start of the string and `,$` matches the comma at the end ..

Comment: how to remove | instead  of ,?

Comment: @ThulasiRam, replace `,` with `\|` so it ends being `test.replace(/^\||\|$/g,'')`

Comment: how would I remove the comma that's followed by a space?

Comment: This is the only truly correct answer, the others will remove any character from the beginning and end of your string, regardless of whether they are a comma or not

Comment: @vick `test.replace(/^,[ ]?|,$/g,'')`

Comment: what if there are more than one commas at start or end and need to be removed all ?

Comment: @anees just add `+` after the commas. `.replace(/^,+|,+$/g,'')`

Answer (score 3):

Below code sample will do this

```
        var str = ",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,";
        str = str.substring(1,str.lastIndexOf(","));
```

Answer (score 2):

`test.substring(1, test.length - 1);` should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am having multiple comma in between the numbers as well.

```js
const str = ",1,8487,8,,848780,888,,";
const parsedStr = str.match(/\d+/g)
document.write(parsedStr)
```

Answer (score -1):

Even easier

```
var result = test.slice(1,-1);
```

Comment: It will remove strings which do not match the "," as well.