# Remove multiple commas from start and end of string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Consider this scenario

```
var str1 = '^^ranbir$$this is first comment,,';
var str2 = ',,^^check$$this is another comment,,';
var str3 = ',,^^mike$$this is 3rd comment, but this is not the last one,,';
```

I want the respective outputs to be

```
console.log(str1) // ^^ranbir$$this is first comment
console.log(str2) // ^^check$$this is another comment
console.log(str3) // ^^mike$$this is 3rd comment, but this is not the last one
```

Basically remove all the commas at the start and end of the string. I was able to remove just one comma from the first and last of the string by trying couple of solutions from stack overflow but could not make it work.

Comment: So what was that you tried? Please share. What if there is only 1 comma at the start/end? Should they be removed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove starting and ending comma from variable in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947507/remove-starting-and-ending-comma-from-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: tried replace(/^,|,$/g,'') once and a couple of other regex expressions. But they remove only single commma from the start and end positions. 
var str = '^^ranbir$$this is first comment,,,,'; //  
expected output : ^^ranbir$$this is first comment

Comment: *by trying couple of solutions from stack overflow* To solve this problem, instead of desperately googling and searching SO and trying every code fragment you find and throwing mud at the wall, stop and read a good regexp tutorial and learn the basic principles. How do I match at the beginning of a string, or the end? How do I match one or more of something? How do I match either this or that? While you're at it, learn the correct terminology for these things--"anchors", "quantifiers", and "alternation". Then you can easily write your own regexp without any searching or cut & paste.

Comment: @torazaburo yes you are right on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the part between the commas:

```js
const re = /^,*(.*?),*$/;
const data = ',,,^^ranbir$$this is first comment,,';
const result = data.match(re);

console.log(result[1]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Unified solution for removing trailing commas and possible spaces at the start and end of the string:

```js
var str3 = ',,, ^^mike$$this is 3rd comment, but this is not the last one  ,,,,  ',
    replaced = str3.replace(/^\s*,+\s*|\s*,+\s*$/g, '');

console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var edited = test.replace(/^,|,$/g,'');
```

^, matches the comma at the start of the string and ,$ matches the comma at the end.

pseudo code: while foo contains ( foo.replace(/^,|,$/g,'') );

source: [remove starting and ending comma from variable in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947507/remove-starting-and-ending-comma-from-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: You could add a `+` quantifier after the commas.

Comment: this will remove only one comma at the start and end of the string

Comment: yes it removes only single comma from the start and end of string.

Comment: pseudo: While foo contains ( foo.replace(/^,|,$/g,'') );