# replace spaces with commas with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string with keywords and I need to check if this string contains spaces and if yes replace them with commas.
the string can be something like "keyword1   keyword2 ,keyword3  keyword4,keyword5"
or any other combination of spaces and commas.
the final result should be a string of keywords separated by commas without any spacing
 like in the following **"keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4,keyword5"**.
for that I tried to do `$("#strId").split('').join(',')`
This done the job but I notice that if I have a string which contains more then one space between each keyword I got multiple commas like that:
original string=(keyword1    keyword2      keyword3)
result string =(keyword1,,,,,,keyword2,,,,,,keyword3)
and I need that it will be with single comma only between each word.
I will appreciate a help on this issue

Thanks

Comment: Take a look in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665829/remove-unwanted-commas-in-javascript

Comment: Is jQuery a requirement or does the link above suit your needs?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Split on any sequence of spaces and commas:

```
str.split(/[ ,]+/).join(',')
```

You might also want to use `filter` to remove empty strings:

```
str.split(/[ ,]+/).filter(function(v){return v!==''}).join(',')
```

Another solution would be to match any sequence that does not contain a space or comma:

```
str.match(/[^ ,]+/g).join(',')
```

Comment: Thanks the first str.split(/[ ,]+/).join(',') did the work like a charm

Answer (score 12):

Use the [`String.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
var newString = yourString.replace(/[ ,]+/g, ",");
```

This says to replace any sequence of one or more spaces or commas in a row with a single comma, so you're covered for strings where the commas have spaces around them like `"test, test,test    test test   , test"`.

(Note: if you want to allow for other whitespace characters beyond just a space use `\s` in the regular expression: `/[\s,]+/g`)

Answer (score 2):

```
alert("test test, test".replace(/[ ,]+/g, ","))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yeefR/

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine using regular expressions and handles any number of spaces:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="strId">keyword1 keyword2 ,keyword3 keyword4,keyword5</div>
<script>

var arr = $("#strId").html().split(/\s+,|\s+/).join(',');
alert(arr);

</script>
```

Also, just FYI: split() is a javascript function, and works fine without jquery too.

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine without using filters

```
var input = $("#seperate").val();
var output = input.split(" ").join(';');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use the replace method form string. you don't have to use jQuery have a look at http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
var text = '           ,        x  ,x,   x,x abc,x,             x                    ,xxxxxx                  ,             ';

text = text.replace(/(\s+)?,(\s+)?/g, ',');
console.log(text);
// => ,x,x,x,x abc,x,x,xxxxxx,

var values = text.split(',').filter(value => value);
console.log(values);
// => ["x", "x", "x", "x abc", "x", "x", "xxxxxx"]
```