# multiply 2 values in javascript where one value has comma separated input

Tags: javascript

Hi all can some one help me I need to multiply comma separated values using javascript, I tried the following but it is not giving the actual result

```
function calculateLinePrice(s, e) {
            var unitPrice = 2,222.00;
            var price = unitPrice.replace(/[^0-9\.,]/g, '')
            var quantity = 10
            if (price != '' && quantity != '') {
                var totalPrice= parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(quantity);
                alert(totalPrice);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: it is alerting me the price as `2`

Comment: And what were you expecting?

Comment: The variable `unitPrice` has a value that's not valid to begin with. Either it's a string containing `"2,222.00"`, or it's a float containing `2222.00`. The current format is not even allowed.

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove commas from a large number, basically? So, turing the string `"2,222.00"` into the integer `2222`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var unitPrice = '2,222.00';
var price = unitPrice.replace(/\,/g,'');
var quantity = 10;
if (price != '' && quantity != '') {
    var totalPrice = parseFloat(price,20) * parseFloat(quantity,20);
    alert(totalPrice);
}
```

Comment: Thanks is it necessary to give `20` with out that also it is working I think

Comment: In that regex if I want to remove special characters then

Comment: In IE it is needed. But it works fine in other browser without 20.

Comment: You only want to use number and . then use regex like  unitPrice.replace(/[^0-9\.]/gi, ''); it will work

Answer (score 0):

`var unitPrice = "2,222.00";`

You do not have it as a string.

you also never use your parameters.

Edit: your regex is also incorrect.

Take a look here: `str.replace(/^[,\s]+|[,\s]+$/g, '').replace(/,[,\s]*,/g, ',');`

This post should also help: [remove unwanted commas in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665829/remove-unwanted-commas-in-javascript)

Comment: This solves the problem only partially. The regex is still wrong.

Comment: You are correct. I had assumed that much would be correct! Thanks!

Comment: Hi I am reading the values from text boxes so I just posted the sample inputs that I am getting while debugging console

Answer (score 0):

Enter price in string format and use split()

```
function cal()
    {
        var unitPrice = "2,222.00";
        var price="";
        var res = unitPrice.split(",");
        for (i=0;i<res.length;i++)
        {
            price=price+res[i];
        }
        //var price = unitPrice.replace(/[^0-9\.,]/g, '')
        var quantity = 10
        if (unitPrice != '' && quantity != '') {
            var totalPrice= parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(quantity);
            alert(totalPrice);
        }
    }
```